# How to delete the last 20 rows of a Sharepoint list with Powershell?

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, powershell

Is it possible to delete the last 20 rows of a sharepoint list with a powershell script?
I use the module pnppowershell.

Gr.

P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Please follow the steps:**

1.This is a test SharePoint list:

[image]

2.Please run the below PowerShell script as an admin:

```
$SiteURL = "https://domain.sharepoint.com/sites/sitename"
$ListName = "listname"
Connect-PnPOnline -Url $SiteURL -Credentials (Get-Credential)
#Get the last 20 row items
$Items = Get-PnPListItem -List $ListName | select -Last 20
ForEach ($Item in $Items)
{
   $ItemID = $Item["ID"]   
   $ItemID
   #Remove the item and saves it in the Recycle Bin
   Remove-PnPListItem -List $ListName -Identity $ItemID -Force -Recycle
   Write-Host "Delete the Item Title : " $Item["Title"] 
}
```

[image]

3.Here is my test:

[image]

[image]